# Function literal with multiple implicit arguments

Tags: function, scala, syntax, arguments, syntax-error

How to define function literal with multiple implicit arguments in Scala? I've tried this way:

```
def create = authAction { (implicit request, user) ⇒ // Syntax error
  Ok(html.user.create(registrationForm))
}
```

but it throws compilation error.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the context of your code, or give a more stand-alone example? This would make it easier to check what's not working with your case. I can't tell where `authAction`, `Ok`, `html` are defined right now. Are you using *Play!* or *Lift* or something else? Thank you

Comment: Yes, my snippet from Play application, it works fine, but with both arguments implicit code would be cleaner.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated in previous answer, you can only define a single implicit parameter for a function literal, but there is workaround.

Instead of multiple implicit arguments you can write function literal as taking multiple argument lists with one argument each. Then it is possible to mark each argument as implicit. Rewriting original snippet:

```
def create = authAction { implicit request ⇒ implicit user ⇒
  Ok(html.user.create(registrationForm))
}
```

You can call it from `authAction` as `f(request)(user)`.

`implicit` keyword duplication is annoying, but at least it works.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can understand of the language specification, as of version 2.9.2 you can only define a single implicit parameter for anonymous functions.

E.g.

```
val autoappend = {implicit text:String => text ++ text}
```

Comment: Anyone know why this is the case? Seems sort of arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar situation as you, implementing an authAction function in Play that would easily pass a user in. You can do it like [lambdas did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079020/350029), with currying; I ended up making my `authAction` function receive the `RequestHeader` implicitly, but pass in both request and user explicitly:

```
def authAction(f: (RequestHeader, User) => Result)(implicit request: RequestHeader) = {
    ...
    val authUser = loadUser(...)
    f(request, authUser)
}
```

And to use it:

```
def create = authAction { (request, user) =>
    Ok(html.user.create(registrationForm))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define an anonymous function with multiple implicit parameters.

To elaborate on @pagoda_5b's answer and @paradigmatic's comment, section 6.23 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) defines anonymous functions like so:

```
Expr ::= (Bindings | [‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
ResultExpr ::= (Bindings | ([‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘:’ CompoundType) ‘=>’ Block
Bindings ::= ‘(’ Binding {‘,’ Binding} ‘)’
Binding ::= (id | ‘_’) [‘:’ Type]
```

As you can see, you can either define a list of parameters *or* a single implicit parameter.

If you need multiple parameters to be implicit, you need to curry them.